# Finding erroneous Json object from json array

Tags: java, json, regex, pattern-matching

I have following type of JSON array (actually I received it as string so I'm trying to convert it to JSON array),

```
[{"Message":{"AccountId":"0","CreationDate":"02-DEC-16","Sbu":null,"ProfileId":"28261723","messageSeqId":69},"Offset":6},
{"Message":{"AccountId":"0","CreationDate":"02-DEC-16","Sbu":null,"ProfileId":"28261271","messageSeqId":76},"Offset":7},
{"Message":{"AccountId":"0","CreationDate":"06-DEC-16","Sbu":null,"ProfileId":"28261871","messageSeqId":99},"Offset":8},
{"Message":{"AccountId":"0","CreationDate":"06-DEC-16","Sbu":null,"ProfileId":"28261921","messageSeqId":101},"Offset":9},
{"Message":{"AccountId":"0","CreationDate":"07-DEC-16","Sbu":null,"ProfileId":"28260905","messageSeqId":105},"Offset":10}]
```

Sometimes this JSON array parsing fails because one JSON objects has fails to parse (I'm using JSON.simple to the JSON parsing). Is there a way to identify the erroneous JSON object?

Here is the code part(ResponseJson is above string that want to convert to JSON array),

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(ResponseJson);
        int jsonArrayLength = jsonArray.size();
        System.out.println("jsonArray length: " + jsonArrayLength);
        if (jsonArrayLength > 0) {
            subscribeMessageEvent(topic,qStart,jsonArrayLength,jsonArray);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what are you using to do the JSON parsing?

Comment: what is your question/error?

Comment: @JoPeyper, sorry. I have updated the questing with it.

Comment: The JSON seems to be vaild, can you please post what exception/error you are getting while parsing JSON?

Comment: Can you also share your code for actually doing the parsing, as I suspect you'll need to catch a [ParseException](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/ParseException.java) and interigate it to find out what went wrong.

Comment: @Apollo, above posted one is correct but the scenario I have mentioned happened randomly. JSON parse fails only because syntax error in a json object.

Comment: well just catch the exception and loop - GIGO (Garbage In / Garbage Out)

Comment: You have solution above :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat, without parsing above string as json array how can I access one by one object?(I couldn't find any method other that using regex)

Comment: as @JoPeyper requested, show us your code

Comment: @Hasitha without parsing it you don't have objects to access. I assume what you want to do is actually keep the good objects in the array and discard the bad ones... this is not going to be easy without making your own JSON parser that will do that when it hits parsing errors and somehow still make sense of the result.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't identify which JSON Object is not properly formed with your current implementation.

Anyways, if you're receiving your input as a String, you could split it into the different messages and then parse them separately. That way you're in control and you can decide what to do with them individually.